# Why does the output of my switch in a do-while loop only print out default statement?

Tags: java, switch-statement, do-while

This is my code which is part of a menu and the output is not what i hoped for

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException{
char choice;

        System.out.println("Menu ");
        System.out.println("1. Nasi Lemak ");
        System.out.println("2. Teh Tarik ");
        System.out.println("3. Roti ");
        System.out.println(" ");
    
        System.out.println( "Place order or type 'q' to exit.");
    
        do {
            System.out.print("Add menu: ");
            choice = (char) System.in.read();
    
            switch (choice) {
                case '1':
                    System.out.println("Nasi Lemak is added to order");
                    break;
                case '2':
                    System.out.println("Teh Tarik is added to order");
                    break;
                case '3':
                    System.out.println("Roti is added to order");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid Input");
            }
        }while(choice!='q');
        System.out.println("Thank you for your order.");
    }

}
```

**Why is it that the following code gives the output?**

```
  Menu
    
    1. Nasi Lemak
    2. Teh Tarik
    3. Roti
    
    Place order or type 'q' to exit.
    Add menu: 1
    Nasi Lemak is added to order
    Add menu: Invalid Input
    Add menu: 2
    Teh Tarik is added to order
    Add menu: Invalid Input
    Add menu: q
    Invalid Input
    Thank you for your order.
    
    Process finished with exit code 0
```

What is my mistake? i've tried brainstorming the problem and i would like to see what you guys have to say.

Comment: It seems the code does exactly what it is written to do. What is your question? and, since "Teh Tarik is added to order" and other similar statements are printed, your premise that it only prints the default is false

Comment: In the last iteration, it prints the default, because you don't have a case for 'q', and 'q' != 1, and 'q' != 2 or 3.

Comment: Assumption: Since `System.in.read()` only reads one char when you enter `1` and hit "enter" the loop reads 2 chars: `'1'` and `'\n'`, and as you can see `'\n'` would be invalid. Try using a scanner, read the next _line_, trim it (in case the user enters a space first), then take the first char or try to parse it to a number.